# Elasticsearch: searching in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following objects in elasticsearch players index.

```
GET /players/_search

"hits": [
     {
        "_index": "players",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "rRI5A8mVRUKKTA08bK90Vw",
        "_score": 0.2712221,
        "_source": {
           "id": "1",
           "first_name": "Lebron",
           "last_name": "James",
           "numbers": [
              {
                 "number": "23",
                 "team": {
                    "city": "Cliveland",
                    "name": "Cavaliers"
                 }
              },
              {
                 "number": "6",
                 "team": {
                    "city": "Maimi",
                    "name": "Heat"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

Now I want to search players who played in "maimi" and had number "23" (there is no such player in this index). I tried

```
GET /players/_search
{
    "query": { 
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "term" : {
                        "numbers.number" : "23"
                    }
                },
                {   "term" : {
                        "numbers.team.city" : "maimi" 
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But elasticsearch still found LeBron. How should I do the correct request to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the structure of your data and how it's indexed : [arrays inner objects](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#object-arrays) are flattened internally.

Actually, your document is indexed in ElasticSearch like this :

```
numbers.number:     [23,6]
numbers.team.city:  [Cliveland,Maimi]
numbers.team.name:  [Cavaliers,Heat]
```

The association between inner objects are lost though and searching for Cliveland Heat number 6 would match this document too.

You should use a [nested](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html#nested-mapping) object mapping to solve this : the inner objects will be kept as they are.